# Cannot run Android ADB command

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am using Android Studio v0.8.14 to create a an Android Wearable app. Since I am new I am following the instructions from the android site: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html#SetupSession

I was able to pair the wearable (Moto 360) with my handled device (Samsung Galaxy S4. Kitkat OS v4.4.2). As per the instructions provided the next goal is to set the debugging session. Here I am trying to run the adb commands as shown:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect localhost:4444
```

But as soon as I the first command my Android Studio gives me the following errors:

```
Cannot find file '/Users/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/forward'
Cannot find file '/Users/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/tcp'
Cannot find file '/Users/Desktop/software/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/localabstract:/adb-hub'
```

Can someone please explain me what is am I doing wrong here?
Thanks
Raj

Comment: Have you followed the instruction about listing the location of adb.exe in the 'Path' environmental variables in Windows?

Comment: I don't think so. However, I am using Mac OS. Would you please share that link? I think that might be the issue.

Comment: Raj, see if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x   I'm not enough of an OS X guy to be able to give a better answer myself.

Comment: Hi Craig, I am running the adb command from the folder where it is installed. For example; "<Android_Studio_Home>/sdk/platform-tools". So I guess it should not be a path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this solution in my mac ... just run the command:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

It's necessary to run this command every time you open a new terminal. Save this in your path to set permanently..